# Where do forests store the carbon?

Tags: carbon-sequestration, forestry

I am beginning to doubt the obvious answer: in the branches and trunk.

> The soil organic carbon (SOC) pool is larger than global vegetation and the atmospheric pool combined
> [source](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fmicb.2016.01247/full)

Forest soils store up to 10 000 times the fungal biomass compared to a field.
[source](https://www.gardenmyths.com/fungal-to-bacterial-ratios/) - not a quote but my interpretation.

Fungal biomass stores more carbon than bacterial - source everywhere e.g. the first link above.

How is the carbon typically distributed in a deciduous and in a coniferous forest? Is most of it above or below ground?

Comment: Don't forget that the soil in an old-growth forest has had a long time to accumulate, from deadwood, fallen leaves etc.  As these decay they release much of their carbon but not all, and not very quickly.  And the topsoil layer in a forest can be rather deep as well as carbon-rich. I can't (without a lot of reading that I don't have time for now) rule out fungal biomass being included in soil biomass, but that's just a matter of accounting